# How to change javafx stage top region

Tags: java, javafx

I want to use javaFx to make stage top region like IDEA menu bar,but i can not find any api in stage to set node .Second picture is my app,the menu bar is in BorderPane top,how to move to stage top?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about a [menu bar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/menu_controls.htm#BABGHADI)?

Comment: @Abra I asking how to set menu bar in stage top

Comment: I think [setting the stage’s style](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initStyle(javafx.stage.StageStyle)) to [UNIFIED](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html#UNIFIED) will do what you want.

Comment: UNIFIED works differently across platforms. On a Mac, visually, I can't tell the difference between a UNIFIED style and no style. Also, on a Mac, Idea does not look like your screenshot.  Mac apps use a common menu bar region for the whole system which is displayed at the top of the screen and not in the window, but Windows has a separate menu bar displayed in each window. Maybe, for a Windows deployment, UNIFIED is the right thing and will provide the desired visuals, (I just can't test it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a possible option is to use a window without decoration `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);` by doing this you remove the 3-buttons and will have an empty stage so you can control it and add whatever you want and for more info you can find an example that serve your case inside this link:
[JavaFx add Window-Control-Buttons to Menubar (IntelliJ like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050673/javafx-add-window-control-buttons-to-menubar-intellij-like)

Comment: `StageStyle.UNIFIED` is probably a better choice.